# Segmentation/Structuring of php and html issue in CI

Tags: codeigniter

I'm having a doubt. What I'm not sure of is how I should segment/structure or implement PHP code into the HTML.

So far, I have structured the coding in following way, echoing out the HTML . But My code didnt work . I have tried to give 'Signout', while the session is present and 'sign-in', while the session is alive.

```
<ul>
<?php if($this->session->userdata('id') == '1')
                        echo '<li class="active"><a class="btn" href='.'"<?php echo base_url();?>'.'index.php/login/log_out">SIGN OUT </a></li>';
                         else
                        {
                     echo '<li class="active"><a class="btn" href='.'"<?php echo base_url();?>'.'index.php/welcome/login">SIGN IN / SIGN UP</a></li>';
                       } ?>
                    </ul>
```

Is it the correct way? where am i getting wrong.

Comment: Whatever html or output should go inside your `view` in codeigniter,Also you include `php` code within your `html`,but in above example you have done reverse,you have added `html` code using `php` which is not a correct way if that is `view` file. Also you have added `php` inside `php` in this code `echo '<li class="active"><a class="btn" href='.'"<?php echo base_url();?>'.'index.php/login/log_out">SIGN OUT </a></li>';` which is wrong

Comment: yes i accept it that i gave a php inside a php which is wrong idea. what should be the correct way to give, provided i kept the file inside the view file already, but saved in as .html

Comment: It should be `.php` not `.html`.Post your view file so that i can show you what you are doing wrong

Comment: I added my full code and i also saved as .php extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a answer to the above structuring 
1. The first thing i saved my view file inside the codeigniter to 'full_calendar.php' which was earlier as 'full_calendar.htm'
2. The second thing I structurally  modified my code as follows:-

```
<ul><?php if($this->session->userdata('id') == '1')
                echo '<li class="active"><a class="btn" href='.base_url().'index.php/login/log_out>SIGN OUT </a></li>';
                 else
                {
             echo '<li class="active"><a class="btn" href='.base_url().'index.php/welcome/login>SIGN IN / SIGN UP</a></li>';
               } ?></ul>
```

And, I now understand that it is mis-match of single quotes and double quotes, which matters the most.